# NSURLSession POST is not working even though is returning 200

Tags: ios, post, nsurlsession

I am trying to post a string and retrieve the response of the server but for some reason it doesn't seem to work, I have used some similar code in the past and it worked fine...
Here is my code and please let me know if you spot the mistake or if you have suggestions

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.NAME.info/test/check.php"];
                    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{


                                      @"Content-Type"        : @"application/json"
                                                               };
                    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
                    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSString* str = @"username=test101";
                    NSData* jsonData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    if (!er

ror) {

                    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                               fromData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {


                                                                                   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                                                   NSString* result2 = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                                                   NSString *secondString = [result2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                                                                                   NSLog(@"*%@*",secondString);
                                                                                   NSLog(@"RESULT RETURNED%@",response.debugDescription);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       }];

                    [uploadTask resume];
                }
```

And the result of doing so is:

```
2015-03-26 19:35:03.305 ChannerApp[690:61802] *error_post*
2015-03-26 19:35:03.305 ChannerApp[690:61802] RESULT RETURNED<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17023a3a0> { URL: http://www.NAME.info/test/check.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 10;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 26 Mar 2015 17:35:35 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6";
} }
```

Comment: Looks like this can't be answered without a description of what the server is expecting. What does the server log say?

Comment: I see the 'Content-Length' is 10. What content is it giving you? Try printing the raw NSData and then use a hexadecimal to text converter to see what you received.